# Take days out of the leap year

Tags: sql, sql-server

At the moment of running the stored procedure I get this message:

> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level
>   exceeded (limit 32)." what could cause that problem

```
----Datos a ingresar
@Id_Inventario int,

@FechaBusqueda date

---Datos dentro del procedimiento almacenados
```

AS
Begin

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @Año int,
@DiasSegunAño int,
@FechaRegistro date,
@CalculoDePorcentajeArticulo float,
@ValorInicial float,
@ValorFinal int,
@ValorActual float,
@DiferenciaDias int,
@Depreciacion float,
@DepreciacionDiaria float,
@Depreciacion_ValorInicial float,
@PorcentajeDepreciacion float,
@Porcentaje float

--FormulaParaSacar el Año de la depresacion
set @Año = Convert(int,(Select Year (@FechaBusqueda)));

--Formula para sacar los dias segun el año
set @DiasSegunAño =(SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Año)+ '/01/01', CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Año+1)+'/01/01'));


--Obtener el Valor del Articulo
set @ValorInicial = (Select Costo_Adquisicion from tbl_Inventario where id_inventario = @Id_Inventario);

--Obtener el Valor Final del Articulo
set @ValorFinal = (@ValorInicial / (@DepreciacionDiaria / @año ));


--Obtener Fecha de Regristo
set @FechaRegistro = (Select Fecha from tbl_Inventario where id_inventario=@Id_Inventario );


-- Insert statements for procedure here
set @DepreciacionDiaria = (@ValorInicial / @PorcentajeDepreciacion) /365;

set @DiferenciaDias = (Select DATEDIFF (Day,@FechaRegistro,@FechaBusqueda));

 set @ValorActual = (@ValorInicial / (@DepreciacionDiaria / @DiferenciaDias ));

set @Depreciacion_ValorInicial = (@ValorActual/@Porcentaje) / 365 --Seleccior la fecha si es 365/366 



 --Obtener el calculo de porcentaje del Articulo
set @CalculoDePorcentajeArticulo = @ValorInicial / @Porcentaje;

---Depreciacion
 set @Depreciacion = @CalculoDePorcentajeArticulo / @Año ;
```

Comment: Please use English within the code base

Comment: Could you explain in more details what you are trying to achieve and what didn't happen as planned?